# Add lines of text to specific line in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the following file, `CHANGELOG.rst`:

```
some text
=========

header
------

* list
* list

header
------

* list
```

I need to add an entry to this file, right after the file's title, so that the updated file will look as the following:

```
some text
=========

new header
----------

* new list

header
------

* list
* list

header
------

* list
```

I add that the

```
new header
----------

* new list
```

part is already present in a `$CHANGES` variable.

I know this can be done with `sed` but I have no idea how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22229231/433940) stackoverflow answer.

Thanks to @mklement0, the code is:

```
sed -i "4 i\
${CHANGES//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}" ./CHANGELOG.rst
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/a  Line which you want to append' filename
```

`-i` is for in-place subsitution

For your example:

```
sed -i "/=========/a ${CHANGES}" file

some text
=========

new header
----------

* new list

header
------

* list
* list

header
------

* list
```

Comment: Looks okay. But can you explain a bit more the use of curly braces and single/double quotes around the `$CHANGES` variable?

Comment: @AndreiHorak Curly braces are not necessary but advisable. Double quotes are for variable expansion in sed. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Alright. However, I am given this error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 147: unknown command: *'`. I believe it's trying to use the contents of `$CHANGES` as some sort of commands, not as plain strings.

Comment: Its because you have `*` in the CHANGES variable. You can disable globbing with `set -f` before you run the sed command and enable it with `set +f` once you are done.

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives me the same error. Also, isn't there another solution for this, without explicitly setting/unsetting things?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `sed` to inject a value into a text file. I'd use `ed`.

```
ed file <<EOF
4i
$yourtext
.
w
EOF
```

This says,

1. "start inserting at the fourth line"
2. insert "$yourtext"
3. stop inserting
4. write.

Answer (score 1):

Use below if you want to ensure you do this for the first occurrence only:

```
CHANGES="line1\nline2"
sed -i "0,/\(^=\+$\)/s//\1\n${CHANGES}/" filename
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `0,` and `\1` do?

Comment: 0 means match up-to first occurrence, ie. it wont do multiple replacements, and \1 places the contents of the 1st group between the escaped () of the regex into the substitute part. In your case we're matching lines starting with one or more =. So we substitute \1 with the matched =.
More info [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4)

Comment: Okay, it makes sense, But it gives me the following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 156: unterminated 's' command`.

Comment: what version of sed are you using? This works on GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: It's the same, `GNU sed version 4.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **ugly** solution using grep:

```
grep -B100000 "=========" CHANGELOG.rst > new.txt
echo >> new.txt
echo "new header" >> new.txt
echo "----------" >> new.txt
echo >> new.txt
echo "\* new list" >> new.txt
echo >> new.txt
grep -A100000 "=========" CHANGELOG.rst >> new.txt
```

grep -A gets the lines after the matching string, and grep -B gets the lines after. It only works if the matching string where you want to split the file exists only once.

Comment: I don't doubt it won't work, but I would like a cleaner approach :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^header/ i\
your content like New Header\
and his content
' YourFile
```

but this occur at every *header*

specificaly (as requested)

```
sed '/^header/ i\
new header\
----------\
\
* new list\

' YourFile
```

Comment: I needed the `sed` for my specific case, not in general. Would appreciate if you could adapt your example to fit my question :)

Comment: I already have the contents which need to be inserted in a variable. Also, what header are you talking about?

Comment: see reply in your other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227122/dont-treat-variable-content-as-special-characters-in-sed)